# How is the la instruction translated in MIPS?

Tags: mips, translation, instructions

I know `la` in MIPS breaks down to `lui` and `ori` but what are the arguments for those instructions?

I looked at this question here [MIPS Pseudo istructions, replacements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568146/mips-pseudo-istructions-replacements) but does the resulting `lui` always use 4097?

Consider the following:

```
       .data
_a:    .space    4
       .text
main:  la       $s0,_a
```

Does that get translated to this?

```
lui    $at,4097
ori    $s0,$at,0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

4097 decimal is 0x1001. This is the upper 16 bits of 0x10010000.

This is the default load address for the start of the `.data` segment in the `mars` simulator.

If you had done `la $s0,main`, the `lui` would be `lui $at,0x0040` because the default start address for `.text` is 0x00400000.

To see the difference, try this program:

```
       .data
_a:    .space    100000
_b:    .space    4
       .text
main:  la       $s0,_b
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lui` loads the upper 16 bits of the address, and the `ori` loads the lower 16 bits of the address. The address can be any 32 bit value, so the `lui` typically does not load 4097.